# Получить все счета из текста рег. выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть необходимость получения списка счетов из какого-то текста, счет - это набор цифр длиной от 20 до 30 символов. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Пример:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply 11586022020000000321391678 dummy text of the
>   printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
>   standard dummy text 4551 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
>   took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
>   electronic typesetting, remaining -711602202000000032154essentially
>   unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
>   Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
>   with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
>   versions 416210200 of Lorem Ipsum.

На выходе получаем: 11586022020000000321391678 и 711602202000000032154

Comment: `/\d{20,30}/` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum ... Lorem Ipsum.";

preg_match_all('#\d{20,30}#', $text, $out);
//preg_match_all('#[0-9]{20,30}#', $text, $out); - Либо так

var_dump($out[0]);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "11586022020000000321391678"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "711602202000000032154"
}
```